# Issue in calling mysql trigger from Shell Script?

Tags: mysql, triggers

```
mysql -h $host -u $user -p$pass $database -e "Create trigger trgQueuedSms
                         AFTER DELETE ON tblSmsQueue
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE VALUE INTEGER;
SET value := (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(),'@',1)='user') ;
IF (value > 0)
THEN
INSERT INTO tblSmsQueueArchive(iID, sMsgId, sUserName, sResellerName,sDistributorName, sMsgText, sType, sSender, sDestination, bDlr, dtLoggedTime, iJobId, sFailReason) VALUES    (old.iID, old.sMsgId, old.sUserName, old.sResellerName,old.sDistributorName,old.sMsgText, old.sType, old.sSender, old.sDestination, old.bDlr, NOW(), old.iJobId, 'DELETED');
END IF;
END;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have semi-colons in your trigger definition you should declare the `DELIMITER` to be something other than semi-colon, and use that `DELIMITER` after `END`. For example, you could use `$$` as the `DELIMITER` like this:

```
mysql -h $host -u $user -p$pass $database --delimiter="$$" -e "Create trigger trgQueuedSms
                         AFTER DELETE ON tblSmsQueue
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE VALUE INTEGER;
SET value := (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(),'@',1)='user') ;
IF (value > 0)
THEN
INSERT INTO tblSmsQueueArchive(iID, sMsgId, sUserName, sResellerName,sDistributorName, sMsgText, sType, sSender, sDestination, bDlr, dtLoggedTime, iJobId, sFailReason) 
VALUES    (old.iID, old.sMsgId, old.sUserName, old.sResellerName,old.sDistributorName,old.sMsgText, old.sType, old.sSender, old.sDestination, old.bDlr, NOW(), old.iJobId, 'DELETED');
END IF;
END $$"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer .I tried the solution.Now am getting error.ERROR 1235 (42000) at line 1: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'

Comment: That means there is already an after delete trigger on that table. If you're trying to replace an existing trigger then you will need to drop the trigger first and then create it.

Comment: I found out that and solved it.Thanks for your reply